# harvest pins from google maps with PHP

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, screen-scraping

How does one scrape all pins(info they hold) from a large google map? This is a good example of what I mean: https://mcdonalds.com.au/find-us/restaurants?qstore=sydney. Since it is a map, I am unable to "inspect elements". All the pins are already in the map so why not just harvest them?

Comment: 1. I do not ask for opinion. 2. I got 3 upvoats for the question. The first answer also got 4 upvoats. Sound like people are interested in this question.

Answer (score 4):

Typically the easiest way is to open the inspector and watch for network traffic, since some network call is going to have to fetch the new pins.

On the page you linked, after some searching (only some of the network requests the map makes is to fetch pin data), I found something along the lines of what you're looking for.

[image: A sample 'pin' response]

From here you have two options:

1. Try and reverse engineer the api-calls. and then systematically call each one and extract the pin data. This looks difficult with the links they offer, but it would be the route I would go down if this needs to be down regularly or with a script. If you want to try this, here's a link to the API request shown above: [API-Request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i14!2i15073!3i9825!1m4!1m3!1i14!2i15074!3i9825!1m4!1m3!1i14!2i15075!3i9825!1m4!1m3!1i14!2i15076!3i9825!1m4!1m3!1i14!2i15077!3i9825!1m4!1m3!1i14!2i15078!3i9825!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i336010613!3m9!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e3!12m1!5b1&callback=_xdc_._7n8dh8&token=69771)
2. Use the regex filter in your browser to filter the requests that contain pins, scroll around the map until you're relatively sure the browser has 'seen' all the pins on the map you want, then copy the responses from all of them and dump them into a text editor or JSON object explorer. From there you can use a regex search to extract the useful info you want and ignore the rest of the junk. This is the path I would go down if this was a one-off scrape that you can do by hand.

Edit: For me, the following ("1m3") was enough to filter out network requests that contain pin location data:

[image: Pin Filter]

I know both of these methods rely on a bit of technical (and likely regular expression) expertise, let me know if there's any more help you need.

As an aside: At first glance, I don't see anything which would clearly be longitude and latitudes for the restaurants, just their names. Their position is likely encoded alongside them, but I'm not sure how important this was to you.

Comment: hey man, thanks for stopping by. Great starting point! I am actually after addresses. I am not sure how they encoded the names or addresses, but  the Queens Park in screenshot isn't the name of restaurant. There is actually no restaurant near Queens Park (which is at Carrington Rd) for extra confusion. I'm still trying to figure out how to convert location data in "base" to something more readable.